# Doctrine2.1 load partial association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Say I have a an entity in Doctrine called Post and it has a bidirectional many-to-one relationship to another entity called Comment.

Say I have a function in Post that serializes the post to JSON and includes a portion of the comments:

```
public function serialize(){
   return array(
          ... other data here ....
          'comments' => $this->getSerializedComments(5),
          'total_comments' => $this->getComments()->count()
   );
}
```

I would like to also write a function getSerializedComments(limit) that only loads up to limit comments in the association (i.e. NOT all of the comments for the post, just 5).  If I understand correctly, if I make the association EXTRA_LAZY, the count() will only run a count query, and not hydrate the whole association.

I would prefer to do all of this in my entity class, and not have to do it in a separate manager or repository function.

I know there's an @OrderBy annotation for To-Many relationships.  Doesn't seem like there's an @Limit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection::slice()`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/v1.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L231-L242), which doesn't [initialize the collection](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.1.0/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php#L662-L683) if it is marked as [`EXTRA_LAZY`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)